# As what for a Data Type is the .Address function saved?

Tags: vba, types

I would like to know what the .Address Function in VBA is saved as. Because I don't know how I would need to 'Dim' my Variable as.
Please Help

This is the Function I mean:

[image]

Comment: `Dim r As Range` will hold it as if you were using `Range("A1")` for example.

Comment: It will saved as `String`. So `Dim add As String` & `add = Function.Address`

Answer (score 0):

It will be Saved as `String`

```
Dim add As String

add = FieldRange.Address
```

Where `FieldRange` is a `Range` Object.

To refer back to the same address you can put `add` in a range object like

```
Range(add).Row
```

Comment: Why would you save it as a String and then use it as a range? Why don't you set the range as a `Range`and use it however you want?

Comment: That's Correct @Damian. But `fnx.Address` gives you a string, and besides sometimes when you are using the range function working with `Activecell` and similar ranges it can change. But if you store it as a String, it will not change. There was a Question couple of weeks back regarding this. I will share the link if i could find it. [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108905/5720144)